# How to use Geoip to get Current city name on NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, geoip

I want to apply Geoip to get my current city's name on Nodejs, then I try to install Geoip package by Npm, but it seems like that it has some mistake when running on Windows, so what should I do to solve the problem.

Comment: Please show the errors you're getting and what you've tried so people know where to start.

Comment: There are no errors, the Geoip package just not supports Windows. So what I want to ask is if there have some solutions instead.

Answer (score 5):

To get Country or City from IP Try this.it's very useful.

```
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');
```

> https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip

```
$ npm install geoip-lite

var ip = "207.97.227.239";
var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);

console.log(geo);

{ 
  range: [ 3479297920, 3479301339 ],
  country: 'US',
  region: 'TX',
  city: 'San Antonio',
  ll: [ 29.4889, -98.3987 ],
  metro: 641,
  zip: 78218 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just published an NPM module for the [IPLocate.io API](https://www.iplocate.io) which I created.

Super easy, no databases to download, and 1,500 free requests per day.

### Install

`npm install node-iplocate`

### Usage

```
const iplocate = require("node-iplocate");

iplocate("8.8.8.8").then(function(results) {
  console.log("IP Address: " + results.ip);
  // IP Address: 8.8.8.8
  console.log("Country: " + results.country + " (" + results.country_code + ")"); 
  // Country: United States (US)
  console.log("Continent: " + results.continent); 
  // Continent: North America
  console.log("Organisation: " + results.org + " (" + results.asn + ")"); 
  // Organisation: Google LLC (AS15169)

  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
  /*
    {
      "ip": "8.8.8.8",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_code": "US",
      "city": null,
      "continent": "North America",
      "latitude": 37.751,
      "longitude": -97.822,
      "time_zone": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "org": "Google LLC",
      "asn": "AS15169"
    }
  */
});

// Or with callbacks
iplocate("8.8.8.8", null, function(err, results) {
  // ...
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
});

// Provide an API key from IPLocate.io
iplocate("8.8.8.8", { api_key: "abcdef" }).then(function(results) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the IP2Location Node.js

https://github.com/ip2location-nodejs/IP2Location

## Pre-requisite

Download the free LITE database from http://lite.ip2location.com/ and use below.

## Install

```
npm install ip2location-nodejs
```

## Usage

```
var ip2loc = require("ip2location-nodejs");

ip2loc.IP2Location_init("/path_to_your_database_file/your_BIN_file.BIN");

testip = ['8.8.8.8', '2404:6800:4001:c01::67', '2001:0200:0102:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000', '2001:0200:0135:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000', '2001:0200:017A:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000'];
for (var x = 0; x < testip.length; x++) {
    result = ip2loc.IP2Location_get_all(testip[x]);
    for (var key in result) {
        console.log(key + ": " + result[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a free - in memory soluition:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@avindak/xgeoip

```
const geoip = require('@avindak/xgeoip');

await geoip.load_memory();
//AU
let res = await geoip.resolve("1.1.1.1");
console.log(res.country_code);
```